# Concatenate Two DataFrames With Hierarchical Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge two DataFrames while creating a multilevel column naming scheme denoting which dataframe the rows came from. For example:

```
In [98]: A=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9.).reshape(3,3),columns=list('abc'))
In [99]: A
Out[99]: 
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8

In [100]: B=A.copy()
```

If I use `pd.merge()`, then I get

```
In [104]: pd.merge(A,B,left_index=True,right_index=True)
Out[104]: 
   a_x  b_x  c_x  a_y  b_y  c_y
0    0    1    2    0    1    2
1    3    4    5    3    4    5
2    6    7    8    6    7    8
```

Which is what I expect with that statement, what I would like (but I don't know how to get!) is:

```
In [104]: <<one or more statements>>
Out[104]: 
     A              B
     a    b    c    a    b    c
0    0    1    2    0    1    2
1    3    4    5    3    4    5
2    6    7    8    6    7    8
```

Can this be done *without* changing the original `pd.DataFrame` calls? I am reading the data in the dataframes in from .csv files and that might be my problem.

Comment: Is the title appropriate? As the answer for you is only a `concat` not a `merge`. Shouldn't the title be "Concatenate two dataframes ..."?

Comment: @Lukas Yes. I just made the change. Sorry about that...I didn't even remember asking this question until your comment came through.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first case can be ordered arbitrarily among A,B (not the columns, just the order A or B)
2nd should preserve ordering

IMHO this is pandonic!

```
In [5]: concat(dict(A = A, B = B),axis=1)
Out[5]: 
   A        B      
   a  b  c  a  b  c
0  0  1  2  0  1  2
1  3  4  5  3  4  5
2  6  7  8  6  7  8

In [6]: concat([ A, B ], keys=['A','B'],axis=1)
Out[6]: 
   A        B      
   a  b  c  a  b  c
0  0  1  2  0  1  2
1  3  4  5  3  4  5
2  6  7  8  6  7  8
```

Comment: In case anyone is confused, `concat` in this answer is `pd.concat()`.

Comment: Hi! What if I need set logic on some column like in `pd.merge(A, B, on='c')`, but A and B have hierarchical columns (gives me a `KeyError`). Without hierarchical columns in A & B it returns the column names with suffixes, but I want the hierarchical columns in the result without a suffix in the column names. Is that possible?

Comment: Answer to my own question: To merge A and B and retain the hierarchical columns and avoid having suffixes in the columns I used this: (inner join on colum 'time') `dfs=[A,B]; for df in dfs: df.set_index('time', inplace=True); 
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='inner', keys='A', 'B')`

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way, which does change A and B:

```
In [10]: from itertools import cycle

In [11]: A.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(cycle('A'), A.columns))

In [12]: A
Out[12]:
   A
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8

In [13]: B.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(cycle('B'), B.columns))

In [14]: A.join(B)
Out[14]:
   A        B
   a  b  c  a  b  c
0  0  1  2  0  1  2
1  3  4  5  3  4  5
2  6  7  8  6  7  8
```

*I actually think this would be a good alternative behaviour, rather than suffixes...*

Comment: If there's no more pandorable* way to do this ATM, then I'm +1 for making it a native keyword-controlled option.  (See how subtle my campaign is?  Maybe I should hand out stickers at PyCon or something. :^)

Comment: @DSM wooo, pycon! Thanks for reminding me: I've got my ticket! :D

Comment: @DSM you should check out Jeff's solution, much better!